# Installing python2 pyyaml

Tags: python, python-2.7, yaml, pyyaml

I have a legacy script that uses Python2 (which I can't modify). It imports module yaml. On older machines, this is satisfied using `pip install pyyaml`.

I'm using a newly built Ubuntu laptop which has had `apt install python2` done. However, there is only a python3 version of pip available. The command `python2 -m pip install pyyaml` says there is no module named pip. I cannot do `apt install python2-pip` or anything like `apt install python2-pyyaml` or `python2-yaml` or similar as there are no such packages available any more. Is there an easy way I can install module yaml for python2 now that python2 is unsupported?

Comment: Look into `get-pip.py`, that can install pip when it doesn't exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do a curl for the following to install pip for python2:

`curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py --output get-pip.py`

Then run
`sudo python2 get-pip.py`

You can then use the command `pip2 --version` tp check if pip is installed and for the correct version of python.